# How to override a property inside the dependency itself?

Tags: java, maven

I have the current scenario, a `pom.xml` with many dependencies, and one of than, let's suppose my dependency **dependency.to.override.property** depends on a version of another tools that I might avoid.

But the artifact **dependency.to.override.property** uses a property called *tools-to-avoid.version* and I need to override this property while I'm inserting the dependency. I've been trying to override it at the *properties* tag but it's not working.

To clarify the scenario, I'm going to expose some code here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.my.groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-parent-pom</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <tools-to-avoid.version>o.p.q.RELEASE</tools-to-avoid.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.dependency.with.dependencies.list</groupId>
                <artifactId>dependency.to.override.property</artifactId>
                <version>x.y.z.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

</project>
```

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to do this to exclude their version of a dependency and use your own instead?

In that case you should exclude their dependency instead. If you do this, any version of the excluded dependency that you have defined yourself will be used instead of both.

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.dependency.with.dependencies.list</groupId>
  <artifactId>dependency.to.override.property</artifactId>
  <version>x.y.z.RELEASE</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
      <groupId>tools.to.avoid</groupId>
      <artifactId>artifact.to.exclude</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions> 
</dependency>
```

Check this link for details: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html

Comment: No, this is not tha case. I want the dependencies, I don't want to declare all of them by myself. But I want to override their version.

Comment: As far as I understand it, the way to do that is to exclude their dependency so that another version of the dependency will be used instead. If you have another dependency that includes a more desired version that will be used instead and you wouldn't have to declare it yourself.